# Falta una entrada para la tabla «» en la cláusula FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql

quiero hacer una pequeña consulta SQL, sin embargo, me aparece el error:

falta una entrada para la tabla «asesorsch_aevento» en la cláusula FROM

El código es muy muy pequeño, y no entiendo a que se debe este error:

```
SELECT * FROM public."AsesorSch_aevento"
WHERE AsesorSch_aevento.startEvent = '2020/10/26'
ORDER BY id
```

La clase de datos que manejo en startEvent es: timestamp

Espero puedan ayudarme, ya que no consigo divisar que es el problema.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM public.AsesorSch_aevento
WHERE AsesorSch_aevento.startEvent = '2020/10/26'
ORDER BY id` Sin las dobles comillas debería funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy ocupando postgresql, y la solución es similar a la comentada por Pablo Lozano, solo que lo único que debo poner en comillas es el nombre del campo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM public."AsesorSch_aevento"
WHERE "startEvent" = '2020/10/26'
ORDER BY id
```

Se quita el AsesorSch_aevento.startEvent y solo se deja startEvent en comillas

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es falta de consistencia al nombrar la tabla. Tanto

```
SELECT * FROM public."AsesorSch_aevento"
WHERE "AsesorSch_aevento".startEvent = '2020/10/26'
ORDER BY id
```

como

```
SELECT * FROM public.AsesorSch_aevento
WHERE AsesorSch_aevento.startEvent = '2020/10/26'
ORDER BY id
```

deberían funcionar.

La razón es que si usas comillas, se diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, mientras que si no las usas, todo se transforma a minúsculas, con lo que
`asesorsch_aevento` es distinto a `AsesorSch_aevento` y no reconoce que sea la misma tabla

Comment: Hola, no funciono lo que comentas, sigue con el mismo error, quiza debi comentarlo, aunque no creo que sea relevante, pero esta base de datos fue creada con Django, aunque realizo consultas a otros campos y no me da problemas, solo me da problema ese campo

Comment: ¿Pero existe el campo?